# What is SoC (system on chip)? Does Renesas V850 have a system on it?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I have experience writing a C program and burning the program into a chip using an IDE provided by the chip manufacturer.

I also heard that there is a concept called SoC, which means an operating system, like Linux, is running on a chip. In this case, I can run my program on the chip just like on a Linux PC.

I don't really know the differences between these two kinds of chips. Are they the same? Can I install Linux on every chip?

And I have to use a chip called [Renesas V850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V850) in my work. Which kind of chip is this V850?

Comment: As for any other meaningless marketing buzz word, there's no formal definition of `SoC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoC is just a marketing term for 'more than a processor on a chip'. It doesn't mean Linux or operating system.

Years ago, each part of a system was on its own chip: processor, serial port, memory, ADC, DAC, etc. You had a PCB and a schematic that tied them all together.

Over time, more and more got integrated into the processor, particularly for application-specific processors and microcontrollers. Today, pretty much only big iron processors like Intel and AMD flagship processors are stand-alone, and even then there's some x86 chip produced that are 'SoC's (like the AMD [Geode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geode_(processor)) line, if that's still around). Everything else has USB ports, serial ports, ADCs, DACs, even wireless radios integrated into the same die.

As for 'what is a Renasas v850?' You'd do better to google that and read the product documentation. It isn't an ARM or MIPs core, and it doesn't appear to support the mainline Linux kernel, only [μClinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CClinux).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very insightful explanation. Guess I have to keep on learning to figure out how to use v850. ;~)

Answer (score 1):

The [Renesas V850 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V850) states that the Linux kernel support for v850 has been absent since version 2.6.27 (which released in 2008).

Typically, you need to know what group your chip belongs to and to read more about it on [Renesas website](http://am.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/v850/index.jsp). They provide all the [documentation](http://am.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/v850/Documentation.jsp#typeVXNlcidzIE1hbnVhbDogSGFyZHdhcmU=) you may need. There is also a section for [application notes and sample code](http://am.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/v850/Documentation.jsp#typeVXNlcidzIE1hbnVhbDogSGFyZHdhcmU=) that may also help.